# I can't repeat a loop because int or float object is not callable

Tags: python, loops, typeerror

I've been trying to make a homework and it requires a loop that receives two inputs and call different functions who returns certain value, the thing is that everything is well until I repeat the input instructions and returns `TypeError: float object is not callable` I mean it worked the first time but the second time does't, it's confusing

```
from sys import exit


def sueldoBruto(valorHora, horaTrabajada):

    return (valorHora * horaTrabajada) * 4

def descuentos(sueldoBruto):

    dctoParaFiscal = sueldoBruto * 0.09

    dctoPension = sueldoBruto * 0.04

    dctoSalud = sueldoBruto * 0.04

    return dctoParaFiscal + dctoPension + dctoSalud

def sueldoNeto(sueldoBruto):

    return sueldoBruto - descuentos(sueldoBruto)

def proviciones(sueldoBruto):
    prima = sueldoBruto * 8.33 / 100
    cesantias = sueldoBruto * 8.33 / 100
    interesCesantias = sueldoBruto * 1 / 100
    vacaciones = sueldoBruto * 4.17 / 100

    return prima + cesantias + interesCesantias + vacaciones


while True:

    decision = input('Quiere ingresar un profesor?: ')
    if decision.lower() == 'si':

        nombre = input('Ingrese nombre completo del docente: ')
        horas = float(input('Ingrese la cantidad de horas trabajadas por semana: '))
        valorHoras = float(input('Ingresa el valor de la hora: '))

        if horas > 40:
            valorHoras = valorHoras * 1.5

        sueldoBruto = sueldoBruto(horas, valorHoras)

        dcto = descuentos(sueldoBruto)

        sueldoNeto = sueldoNeto(sueldoBruto)

        proviciones  = proviciones(sueldoBruto)

        print(f'El sueldo bruto del docente {nombre} es: {sueldoBruto} mensuales')
        print(f'Los descuentos de parafiscales, salud y pension son:  {dcto} mensuales')
        print(f'El sueldo neto del docente {nombre} es {sueldoNeto}: mensuales')
        print(f'Las proviciones por prima, cesantias, interes de cesantias y vacaciones son: {proviciones}')
    else:
        exit()
```

`
Then it returns something like that

```
Quiere ingresar un profesor?: si
Ingrese nombre completo del docente: Emanuel Leal
Ingrese la cantidad de horas trabajadas por semana: 42
Ingresa el valor de la hora: 5000
El sueldo bruto del docente Emanuel Leal es: 1260000.0 mensuales
Los descuentos de parafiscales, salud y pension son:  214200.0 mensuales
El sueldo neto del docente Emanuel Leal es 1045800.0: mensuales
Las proviciones por prima, cesantias, interes de cesantias y vacaciones son: 275058.0
Quiere ingresar un profesor?: si
Ingrese nombre completo del docente: Ana Julia
Ingrese la cantidad de horas trabajadas por semana: 37
Ingresa el valor de la hora: 5600
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/master/Documentos/proyectos/misiontic/ciclo1/semana5/reto4/reto4.py", line 43, in <module>
sueldoBruto = sueldoBruto(horas, valorHoras)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def sueldoNeto(sueldoBruto):` returns a number, right? You call:

```
sueldoBruto = sueldoBruto(horas, valorHoras)
```

Now `sueldoBruto` *is that number*. So when you try to call `sueldoBruto(horas, valorHoras)` again, you'll be trying to call that number, which is an error.

You shouldn't call your variables the same names as your functions - Python will happily use the name `sueldoBruto` to refer to a function, a string, a number - absolutely anything.

All of these lines have this problem:

```
sueldoBruto = sueldoBruto(horas, valorHoras)
sueldoNeto = sueldoNeto(sueldoBruto)
proviciones  = proviciones(sueldoBruto)
```